# Cannot call value of non-function type

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, swift3

Having issues trying to convert this to Swift 3.0.

I have:

```
 public func calendarView(_ view: DDCalendarView, eventsForDay date: Date) -> [Any]? {
        let daysModifier = (date as NSDate).days(from: Date())
        //var daysMod = date.days(from: Date())

        //var newE = self.events(forDay: daysModifier as Int) as NSArray
        var Good = self.events(forDay: daysModifier) as Any
        var dates = [NSMutableArray]()
        var e:DDCalendarEvent

        for e in Good as! [AnyObject] {

            if e.dateBegin(isEqual(date)) as! Bool ==  true || e.dateEnd(isEqual(date)) as! Bool ==  true {
                dates.append(e as! NSMutableArray)
            }
   }

       return dates
    }
```

the condition if e.dateBegin(isEqual(Date)){} is giving this error.
while in Objective-C Code Code is:

```
- (NSArray *)calendarView:(DDCalendarView *)view eventsForDay:(NSDate *)date {
    //should come from db ;) NOW using testdata
    NSInteger daysMod = [date daysFromDate:[NSDate date]];
    NSArray *newE = [self eventsForDay:daysMod]; //always today ;)

    NSMutableArray *dates = [NSMutableArray array];
    for (DDCalendarEvent *e in newE) {
        if([e.dateBegin isEqualDay:date] ||
           [e.dateEnd isEqualDay:date]) {
            [dates addObject:e];
        }
    }
    return dates;
}
```

and its returning Bool Value for isEqualDay Function

```
- (BOOL)isEqualDay:(NSDate *)date {
    NSDateComponents *compA = self.currentCalendarDateComponents;
    NSDateComponents *compB = date.currentCalendarDateComponents;
    return ([compA day]==[compB day] && [compA month]==[compB month ]&& [compA year]==[compB year]);
}
```

Any Solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

This line:

```
if e.dateBegin(isEqual(date)) as! Bool ==  true || e.dateEnd(isEqual(date)) as! Bool ==  true {
```

should be:

```
if e.dateBegin.isEqualDay(date) == true || e.dateEnd.isEqualDay(date) == true {
```

This assumes you have also translated the `isEqualDay:` method as an extension function on `Date`.

BTW - there are many other problems in your translation. The above only covers that one specific line you ask about in your question.

The following should be what you want:

```
public func calendarView(_ view: DDCalendarView, eventsForDay date: Date) -> [Date] {
    let daysModifier = date.days(from: Date()) // return Int
    let newE = self.events(forDay: daysModifier) // return [DDCalendarEvent]

    var dates = [Date]()
    for e in newE {
        if e.dateBegin.isEqualDay(date) == true || e.dateEnd.isEqualDay(date) == true {
            dates.append(e)
        }
    }

    return dates
}
```

Comment: @rmddy let me apply your code as you suggest.will get back to you soon .btw you are mastermind.

Comment: this function return an array public func calendarView(_ view: DDCalendarView, eventsForDay date: Date) -> [Any] {
instead of date i need to put any as it is datasource method or else it is showing error ..

Comment: OK, feel free to make a few changes. I know nothing about your `DDCalendarView` class. I just attempted to offer a better translation. There are likely going to be a few small changes needed.

Comment: can you convert my objective code for datasource function please all i need is that only . i used swiftify for converting objc to swift

Comment: I did convert it. That's all of the code in my answer.